# problem during installing wordpress 

Tags: wordpress

Hi all I am new to wordpress and I am following [5 min. installation method](http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress#Famous_5-Minute_Install)  and stoped at 5th step . As I want to install it on my local machine that is localhost , where do I have to put all the files and sub directory of wordpress folder so that I can do the installation .

if any one have idea about editing wp-config.php for localhost please share with me .

Comment: This isn't really a programming question. You might be better off asking at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is place all the contents of the Wordpress directory under a directory (with the name of your project, for example) on the root of your webserver. This directory will depend on your system. Eg. under Ubuntu, and using Apache the default is /var/www.

The essential fields of your wp-config.php that you have to fill in are

DB_NAME

DB_USER

DB_PASSWORD

DB_HOST (this is localhost)

That you have to configure to match your DB configuration.

Answer (score 1):

You do need to firstly install WAMP or LAMP which are both used as local web servers.
During the installation of WAMP, it asks you to name a folder to place all the web services in. e.g. c:\server

Once you do that you can put the files in the WordPress zip file into a folder c:\server\www
Once you run the WAMP server you can use your browser to navigate to your WordPress site.

Here is an article about [how to install WordPress](http://121wordpress.com/wordpress-step-by-step-installation/)

Answer (score 0):

you must install a program like **[wamp server](http://www.wampserver.com/)** and copy wordpress directory in wamp/www then create a database and fill wp-config.php
for fill username in wp-config use **'root'** and for password use **' ' (empty)**.